# SQL retornando erro ao selecionar campo inexistente

Tags: sql, oracle

Tem um sistema que várias empresas utilizam, porém não são informadas as alterações nas tabelas do banco.

Teria como criar um select que não retornasse erro ao não encontrar um campo retirado recentemente de uma tabela?

Código:

```
SELECT 
    cd_cliente,
    nm_cliente,
    dt_imp_banco 
FROM 
    dbamv.cliente
WHERE 
    dt_imp_banco IS NOT EXISTS;
```

**Mensagem de Erro:**

> ERROR:  column "dt_imp_banco" does not exist LINE 4:  dt_imp_banco 
>            ^ SQL state: 42703 Character: 44

Comment: Não que saiba.Pois o interpretador é chamado e checa a síntaxe.

Comment: Minha meta é criar um select que ignore os campos que não existem, no caso o campo:  dt_imp_banco  não existem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6352261/4551469) do *SOEN*, é possível, mas não diretamente. Ela sugere checar se a coluna existe e só então executar o *select*:

```
DECLARE
  v_column_exists number := 0;  

BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO v_column_exists
  FROM user_tab_cols
  WHERE column_name = 'dt_imp_banco' AND table_name = 'cliente';

  IF (v_column_exists > 0) THEN
      SELECT cd_cliente, nm_cliente, dt_imp_banco FROM dbamv.cliente;
  END IF;
END;
```

---

**editado**

Após os comentários nessa resposta a ideia segue a mesma, checar se a coluna existe antes da consulta. Porém, como a necessidade é que o select seja feito independentemente da coluna existir (no caso de não, a consulta ser feita pelos demais campos), a sugestão seria criar validações individuais por coluna que possa existir.

```
DECLARE
  exist_dt_imp_banco number := 0;  

BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO exist_dt_imp_banco
  FROM user_tab_cols
  WHERE column_name = 'dt_imp_banco' AND table_name = 'cliente';

  SELECT
    cd_cliente,
    nm_cliente,
    CASE exist_dt_imp_banco WHEN 0 THEN null ELSE dt_imp_banco END
  FROM dbamv.cliente;
END;
```

Assim, caso a coluna exista (no exemplo, `exist_dt_imp_banco > 0`), seria consultado o valor da coluna no banco; caso contrário, traria `null`.

**DETALHE:** o ponto é que em casos que em seja necessário validar muitas colunas, o código ficaria muito grande (e talvez custoso).

Segue um exemplo com três colunas a serem validadas.

```
DECLARE
  exist_dt_imp_banco number := 0;  
  exist_dt_imp_banco_2 number := 0;  
  exist_dt_imp_banco_3 number := 0;  

BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO exist_dt_imp_banco
  FROM user_tab_cols
  WHERE column_name = 'dt_imp_banco' AND table_name = 'cliente';

  SELECT count(*) INTO exist_dt_imp_banco_2
  FROM user_tab_cols
  WHERE column_name = 'ADD_TMSdt_imp_banco_2' AND table_name = 'cliente';

  SELECT count(*) INTO exist_dt_imp_banco_3
  FROM user_tab_cols
  WHERE column_name = 'dt_imp_banco_3' AND table_name = 'cliente';

  SELECT
    cd_cliente,
    nm_cliente,
    CASE exist_dt_imp_banco WHEN 0 THEN null ELSE dt_imp_banco END,
    CASE exist_dt_imp_banco_2 WHEN 0 THEN null ELSE dt_imp_banco_2 END,
    CASE exist_dt_imp_banco_3 WHEN 0 THEN null ELSE dt_imp_banco_3 END
  FROM dbamv.cliente;
END;
```

Comment: Agora que entendi a pergunta !

Comment: massa.. então se souber alguma forma _"direta"_, já responde :P

Comment: Direto na query acho que não existe. Sua resposta acho que está no caminho certo. :D

Comment: Veja bem..  a tabela existe... porem o campo não!

Comment: A minha meta é criar um select que ignore os campos que não existem

Comment: São muitas validações? Porque uma alternativa seria usar um _case_ no próprio select..

Comment: como seria isso? Poderia mostrar algum exemplo ?

Comment: O SQL teria ainda de ser dinâmico pois do contrário daria erro de compilação no plsql.

Comment: OK. quanto ao exemplo, poderia informa algum  ?

Comment: Eu não faria esta solução que você quer pois ela é perigosa a coluna pode ser importante para a aplicação.faria um bom e velho controle de versões.Em que seu sistema foi implementado ?

Comment: Poes é não existe um controle de versão eficaz. As tabelas são alteradas sem aviso. o que ferra o sistemas

Comment: Temos de corrigir cada cliente porque o select dá erro se uma das colunas não esta na lista.

Comment: Meu proposito é criar um select que traga os campos existes e ignore os campos faltantes

Comment: Então você não tem os "candidatos"? Se não, acho que a questão é um pouco diferente do que estamos tentando até agora.. existiria uma abordagem mais fácil, tipo `select * from dbamv.cliente`

Comment: Já tinha pensado...Porém o sistema traria tudo. Imagina vc um sistema que trás 100.000 clientes